# Setting zIndex of CartoDB.js layer on top of Google Map's GroundOverlay?

Tags: carto, google-maps-api, carto-js

I am trying to combine the [Google Maps API Ground Overlay example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple) with [CartoDB.js example using Google Maps](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/gmaps.html). It appears both APIs are displaying their layers correctly.

However, the ground overlay is always displayed on top. I would like to see the positions from the CartoDB viz layer to appear on top of the ground overlay. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a couple of different things, and based on information from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063476/82180) post and [Google Maps Custom Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays). I ended up with this solution:

```
      // Constructor
      function CustomOverlay(map) {
        this.setMap(map);
      }

      // Inside main function
      // ...
      /*
         Custom Overlay

         Overlay holds the Pane that holds GroundOverlay, so we can
         accquire the handle to set the appropriate zIndex.

         See: 
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays. 
         https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063476/82180
      */
      var customOverlay;
      CustomOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
      overlay = new CustomOverlay(map);

      CustomOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
        var panes = this.getPanes();    
        panes.overlayLayer.style['zIndex'] = 10; <!-- Magic # based on experimentation! -->
      }

      CustomOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
        // NOOP
        // The overlay is just a container, we are not adding any custom
        // graphics/text onto it.
      }
```