# Controlling layer order between cartoDB and Google maps Fusion layer

Tags: carto, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to control the layer order between a cartoDB layer and a Google FusionTables layer, on a google base map. The CartoDB layer always displays underneath, whereas i want it on top. I have found methods to order layers within Google, or within CartoDB, but not how to order them with respect to each other.

I have mocked up an example here:
http://codepen.io/rich_3po/pen/Bjoadr

(the yellow points are from CartoDB, and should display on top of the routes)

How do i go about achieving this?

My question is similar to [Ordering Cartodb torque visualization over Google Maps heatmap layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120938), but the answer wasn't clear and didn't seem to apply to my case

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this by following the answer at [Setting zIndex of CartoDB.js layer on top of Google Map's GroundOverlay?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111486)

I dont fully understand what the code is doing, but it works...